# Xamarin Bindable property

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I've created my own custom control in Xamarin in which I want to set a property from the xaml code.

```
<MyClass MyProperty="10" />
```

I've tried to use a BindableProperty in order to get it work, my code behind looks like:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty BindProp = BindableProperty.Create(
                  nameof(MyProperty),
                  typeof(int),
                  typeof(MyClass),
                  0);

public int MyProperty
{
   get
   {
      return (int)GetValue(BindProp);
   }
   set
   {
      SetValue(BindProp, value);
   }
}
```

I expedted that MyProperty should be initiated to 10. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think your `typeof(MyClass)` needs to be `typeof(myControl)` or `<local:myControl MyProperty=10 />` should be `<local:MyClass MyProperty=10 />` depending on what your custom control class is actually named

Comment: @Nick Yes, of course, you're right. I've edited my question. But it's still not working. MyProperty is never being set.

Comment: Can you provide more of your classes and the page/view you are using it on and is your xaml code above exactly how you're trying to use it? If it is that isn't valid xaml, which your custom class is missing its namespace and there are no quotes around MyProperty `<local:MyClass MyProperty="10" />`

Comment: @Nick You're right, I forgot the quotes when I wrote it here, it was correct in my code. Everything works fine now, it proved that my actual error was at another place in the code. Thank you!

Comment: You should look into turning xaml compilation on it would throw and error in xaml when you build if there's a syntax error